# Unknown type: code || getting this error in sanity as schema error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I Have installed sanity code-input plug-in using yarn. Now I'm having this error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wZhk.png)

Here I'm using type code

```
    {
      name: 'exampleUsage',
      title: 'Example usage',
      type: 'code',
    },
```

Code input is successfully installed

[code input in Node module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlKqj.png)

My sanity version

version 2.30.6

every thing is clear according to sanity docs

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when I tried to use [color-input](https://www.sanity.io/plugins/color-input) plugin , the problem is that I installed sanity v2 and then installed the plugin for v3 when I should have searched for the v2 plugin instead .
If you go to check code-input [docs](https://www.sanity.io/plugins/code-input) you will see the install command for each version .
[image]

So if your problem is the same as mine a solution would be

```
yarn remove @sanity/code-input
yarn add @sanity/code-input@studio-v2
```